# Replace special character in a data frame column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below

```
Des              NewColumn
a                27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82
c                32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31
```

I need / to be replaced by > and below is what i need

```
Des              NewColumn
a                27.82 > 23.65 > 27.82
c                32.25 > 31 > 32.25 > 31
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("[/]", ">", df1$NewColumn)
```

or use `chartr`

```
chartr("/", ">", df1$NewColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stringr` library:

```
 library(stringr)
 str_replace_all(df$NewColumn,"/",">")
```